# Syntax Error: Error: Failed to load config "@vue/prettier" to extend from

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project with vuejs add vuetify I  install dhe plugin prettier after that I made configure  in file package.json
[image]

But me display this error when I run npm run serve.

[image]

Comment: Try installing @vue/eslint-config-prettier

Comment: @Luka thanks for your answer but me dispal this  error after run this command:

Comment: PS C:\Users\Vena\Desktop\meal-prep>  npm i @vue/eslint-config-prettier
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: meal-prep@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@6.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^6.7.2" from the root project

Comment: I am trying to remember what I have done in this place, but for the sake of making sure, if the project is not brand new, try to check which node version was it built upon. Usually, I see these issues with usage of wrong node v. After switching to the potential correct one, delete package-lock and node modules and reinstall everything

Comment: installing `npm install --save-dev @vue/eslint-config-prettier` worked